# Error while retrieving the results for the job parts in BulkMutateJob

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

I have a question about google adwords API service: BulkMutateJob.

I'm trying to update a lot of adwords for different groups. I create a job and it is being run successfully and gets the status "COMPLETED" but then I want to retrieve the results for the parts for this job and get the error:

```
inner_fault: !ruby/exception:SOAP::FaultError 
message: "[RangeError.TOO_HIGH @ selector.resultPartIndex]"
```

The code is:

```
if status == 'COMPLETED' and error == false
  puts 'Job completed!'
  # Retrieve the results for the parts.
  0.upto(parts) do |part_index|
    selector = bulk_mutate_job_srv.module::BulkMutateJobSelector.new
    selector.jobIds = [job_id]
    # Retrieve results for the first part.
    selector.resultPartIndex = part_index
    results = bulk_mutate_job_srv.get(selector)
    if results and results.entries
      results.each do |result|
        puts 'Part %d/%d of job #%d has successfully completed' %
        [part_index + 1, job[:parts], job_id]
      end
    else
      raise 'Error retrieving job results; aborting.'
    end
  end
else
  puts "Job failed: #{get_response.entries[0].failureReason}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is indicating that you are passing in a negative number for resultPartIndex.  FYI, the official AdWords API forum is here: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/forum.html